# Getting 502 Bad Gataway after a service call in my app

Tags: spring, rest, http-status-codes

I have seen there are similar post but actually I do not know how to analyze this problem to understand real cause. I have a cloud app working in a cluster and I am calling an Rest service. As a result I am getting 502 bad gateway error. When I check the logs, I can see with the same parameters I sometimes get this error and sometimes everything is fine.

So I do not know how can I find the reason of this error? Is this problem might be on my application or from the other service which I am calling. I would like to ask how can I know if the problem is on my side and what can I do to understand root cause.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$BadGateway: 502 Bad Gateway
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:83) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: It should be from other service which you are calling. Worth to check access logs of other service (load balancer or http server logs)

Answer (score 0):

502 error means somehting happened on the other side, your application either not running or there some network problem, so there no way to reach your app, and it is as good as not running. Definitely need to check nginx logs and everything in between your app client, from which you sending request.